# Extracting a changeable string from a list and insertion in Python

Tags: python, string, insertion, dd

I have a list that looks like this:

```
['2    19   2839475239874 hda']
```

I need to extract the hda from the end. However, the hda may not always be the last chunk, hda may not always be only 3 letters (it could be 4 or 5, and it could include numbers); BUT it will always start with the letter 'h'.

After the hda is successfully extracted, I then need to insert that chunk into a dd command. That looks like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hda bs=512 count=1
```

But if the hda could be different each time I run the dd command, I need a way to have the 'hda' part of the dd command changeable.

Sorry if this is confusing, I am a beginner and confused myself! I've tried using startswith for extraction, but can't even get past there!

Comment: `[' 2 19 2839475239874 hda']` a list with only one element? Why not just use a string, or there are more strings like this in the list?

Comment: @zhangyangyu No, this is the only list, and hda is the only string/chunk I need. Sorry if I didn't understand your questions properly.

Comment: @zhangyangyu, I think he just misstyped it. Read `['2','19','2839475239874','hda']` ;].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply like so:

```py
lst = ['2    19   2839475239874 hda']

# Extracting the device part
dev = filter(lambda s: s[0] is 'h', lst[0].split())[0]

# Inserting it
cmd = 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/{0} bs=512 count=1'.format(dev)
```

You will want to check the case where you don't have any h-word in your list though.

Comment: The program I've created was supposed to print out this:

['2    19   2839475239874 hda']

as 

['2

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> thelist = ['2    19   2839475239874 hda']
>>> [item for item in thelist[0].split() if item[0] == 'h'][0]
'hda'
```